# C: EOF detection & fgetc

Tags: c, eof, fgetc

OBJECTIVE:
How to implement EOF successfully to stop the infinite loop?

**part where the function is called:**

```
do {
    pId = readInputField(fptr, DELIMITER_SPACE);
    pName = readInputField(fptr, DELIMITER_SEMICOLON);
    pDob = readInputField(fptr, DELIMITER_SPACE);
    pHobbyList = readInputField(fptr, DELIMITER_NEWLINE);
} while (NULL != pId
         && NULL != pName
         && NULL != pDob
         && NULL != pHobbyList);
```

**function definition:**

```
char* readInputField(FILE* fPtr, const char delimiter) {
    int numCharRead;
    char bufferString[MAX_LENGTH_INPUT];
    char *pBufferString;

    numCharRead = 0;

    // flush: if spaces are found
    ' ' == (bufferString[numCharRead] = fgetc(fPtr)) ? 0 : numCharRead++;

    // get chracter array before delimiter
    while (delimiter != bufferString[numCharRead - 1]
            && numCharRead < MAX_LENGTH_INPUT) {
        bufferString[numCharRead++] = fgetc(fPtr);
    }

    // exclude delimiter from the string
    bufferString[numCharRead - 1] = '\0';

    printf("numCharRead=  \"%d\"\n", numCharRead);

    printf("delimiter:    \"%c\"\n", delimiter);
    printf("bufferString: \"%s\"\n", bufferString);

    pBufferString = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(bufferString));

    /* deleted:
    pBufferString = bufferString;
    return EOF == bufferString[numCharRead - 1] ? NULL : pBufferString;
    */
}
```

**sample input:**

```
VIC Lee, Victoria; 02/25/90 Knitting;Photography;Dance;
```

**sample output:**

```
numCharRead=  "4"
delimiter:    " "
bufferString: "VIC"
numCharRead=  "14"
delimiter:    ";"
bufferString: "Lee, Victoria"
numCharRead=  "9"
delimiter:    " "
bufferString: "02/25/90"
numCharRead=  "28"
delimiter:    "
"
bufferString: "Knitting;Photography;Dance;"

// after this, infinite loop begins with garbage data
```

My call is to look at return statement above. For some reason, it does not detect if it is EOF.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

---

**updated:**
Thanks @JoachimPileborg! I have updated my code below:

```
  // check for EOF
    if(bufferString[numCharRead-1] == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        pBufferString = malloc(sizeof(char*));
        strcpy(pBufferString, bufferString);
        return pBufferString;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that `fgetc` returns an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: Oh, and you have an ever worse problem: You return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. I updated the code above to fix pointer problem. Regarding `fgetc`, I don't even get a warning, and the results are just as expected. What would you suggest to replace `fgetc`?

Comment: You allocate almost four or eight times more memory than needed. `sizeof(char*)` is 4 or 8. It's enough to allocate `strlen(...) + 1` bytes. _And_ you should use `strcpy` to copy the string, now you change the pointer to point to the local variable (so still return a pointer to a local variable).

Comment: `' ' == (bufferString[numCharRead] = fgetc(fPtr)) ? 0 : numCharRead++;`... this is a really convoluted way of expressing `if ((bufferString[numCharRead] = fgetc(fPtr))) numCharRead++;`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have modified the code above. I am not sure if I understand "change the pointer to point to the local variable (so still return a pointer to a local variable)." Could you please explain further?

Comment: @dreamlax They are not equal. `' ' == (bufferString[numCharRead] = fgetc(fPtr)) ? 0 : numCharRead++;` increments numCharRead if and only if the character read is not space(or `' '`). I bet there is prettier way to code this one though.

Comment: @JaneBerman oops typo, what I meant was `if ((bufferString[numCharRead] = fgetc(fPtr)) != ' ') numCharRead++;` ... this increments numCharRead only if the character read is not a space. The ternary operator isn't always a replacement for `if`. An `if` statement reads much nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `EOF` where you read from file, as

```
// flush: if spaces are found
' ' == (bufferString[numCharRead] = fgetc(fPtr)) ? 0 : numCharRead++;
if(bufferString[numCharRead-1] == EOF)
    return NULL;

while (delimiter != bufferString[numCharRead - 1]
            && numCharRead < MAX_LENGTH_INPUT) {
    bufferString[numCharRead++] = fgetc(fPtr);
    /* check for EOF */
    if(bufferString[numCharRead-1] == EOF)
        return NULL;
}
```

You also have problems that mentioned in comments by @Joachim Pileborg

- `fgetc` returns `int` not `char`
- You are returning `bufferString` which is local to function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohan! The infinite loop occurred in the flush. I have modified the code; it has not stopped the infinite loop!

Answer (score 1):

Can't write code in a comment so I post this as an answer.

You have (or at least had) this code in the question:

```
pBufferString = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(bufferString));
pBufferString = bufferString;
return EOF == bufferString[numCharRead - 1] ? NULL : pBufferString;
```

In the first line above you allocate memory and makes `pBufferString` point to that memory.

In the second line you then make `pBufferString` point to the local array `bufferString`, so you no longer have a pointer to the memory you allocated with `malloc`, causing a memory leak (and a probable crash when you later try to `free` that pointer).

You then return `pBufferString`, which is now pointing to the local array, leading to undefined behavior, as the stack-memory occupied by the local array is no longer valid after the function returns.

Besides the above problem, you allocate almost four or eight times as much memory as needed. The size of a pointer is four or eight bytes (depending on if you are on a 32 or 64 bit platform), but a `char` is only one byte. It's enough to use `strlen(bufferString) + 1` as the size to allocate:

```
pBufferString = malloc(strlen(bufferString) + 1);
```

You need the `+ 1` because the string terminator character is not included in the string length.

Comment: Now, it's much more clearer. I appreciate your input! What would be your replacement of `fgetc` on the above code? What is the significance of `fgetc` returning `int`, not `char`?

Comment: @JaneBerman Technically `255` is a valid character. Unfortunately it can also be seen as -1 if using `char`. -1 for a `char` is not the same as -1 for an `int`.